# Possible to connect Mac mini to WinXP/Vista laptop in order to see Mac mini's screen on laptop screen?

Tags: windows-xp, mac, windows-vista, laptop

I'm trying to avoid lugging a monitor around by carrying just my laptop and Mac mini and using the laptop screen to see what's going on with the mini. Bonus points for being able to use the laptop keyboard and mouse to control the Mac mini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ScreenRecycler](http://www.screenrecycler.com/ScreenRecycler.html) (screen sharing) and maybe combines it with [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) (mouse + keyboard support).

Otherwise, you can turn on *Screen Sharing* on the Mac Mini and use any VNC client on the laptop to control it.

[image: screen sharing]

Comment: For this setup, you would check that the mini can boot headless (no keybd/mouse/monitor) with no problems, so you could just plug it in, wait, and concect via VNC.

Another consideration is how the two machines connect to each other to establish the VNC connection.  If you are looking to use the laptop on an internet WiFi you would have to ensure the mini connects to the same network via its WiFi.  Alternatively if the laptop has an ethernet port, you could connect the two machines via a crossover cable and configure network to match. Connect to mini via ethernet and internet via wifi.

Comment: Thanks, Screen Sharing and UltraVNC did the trick. Thanks to joet3ch for the UltraVNC tip; wish I could mark both answers as "correct".

Answer (score 1):

VNC will accomplish this task for you.  A variety of VNC clients exist, UltraVNC would be a good starting point.